# Different results of 'ps aux | grep x' if entered manually and done via script

Tags: bash, grep, init.d, ps

It was probably a bad method, but I was running `ps aux | grep x | wc -l` as part of the if statement in a script. When I ran this from the command line as a regular user, the result would be 1 if the process wasn't running, because of that annoying quirk whereby the grep process turns up.

That's fine and well, but I logged the results, and most of the time `ps aux | grep x | wc -l` run as an /etc/init.d script would return 0 lines. Why would that be?

Comment: Can you post the script? However, to get rid of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) right from the start, just use `pgrep` to check if the process is running or not.

Comment: What's the most {efficient,reliable} way to check in an if statement if the process is running via `pgrep`?

Comment: Instead of `ps aux | grep x`, you'd do `pgrep x`. Try it on a running process and check if it returns the correct pid.

Comment: right, so `if [[ $(pgrep x | wc -l) = 1 ]]` should work?

Comment: @AlaaAli It does. It returns the list of all the running processes matching that name. Open `gedit` and run `pgrep ^gedit$`, then cross check the output with `ps -aux | grep gedit`.

Comment: @cfye14 like this: `if pgrep "x" > /dev/null; then echo "RUNNING"; else echo "NOT RUNNING"; fi`. `/dev/null` is used to discard the output of `pgrep` (which is the pid number). Or, if your if is pretty simple, you can do `[[ $(pgrep "x") ]] && echo "RUNNING" || echo "NOT RUNNING"`.

Comment: Yes, because in this case you don't want neither < 1 nor > 1, however you don't need the double brackets, also enclose the process name between a caret and a dollar sign: `if [ $(pgrep ^x$ | wc -l) = 1 ]; then [...]`;

Comment: explain the caret and dollar sign?

Comment: @kos use `-x` instead of `^...$`. Also, `pgrep` can count matches (`-c`). Though Alaa's `if ` test is better.

Comment: Fair enough, you can use `-x` instead of matching using anchors, so that would be `pgrep -x x`. However @muru I'm missing the added value aside from shortness (referring to the second test, don't know which one you're talking about)

Comment: The value being: Why count anything when `pgrep`'s exit status tells you what you want to know (that the program is running).

Comment: @muru [That was intended](http://askubuntu.com/questions/643392/different-results-of-ps-aux-grep-x-if-entered-manually-and-done-via-script?noredirect=1#comment921489_643392), altough it's not clear what OP is going to do with the script.

Comment: cfye14 What do you have to do with the process after the test? What about multiple processes?

Comment: @kos, I am checking if a process is running. If not, restart it. If it is, cool.

Comment: Fine, then just use Alaa Ali's if statement and you're set.

Comment: Curious: does your process fork at startup?

Comment: @muru, without knowing the technical meaning of forking, `ps aux | grep x` shows two processes (tho `pgrep` doesn't catch one), one the init script, and the other a script in my home directory that does the work.

Comment: @cyfe14 often when grepping for a process the grep itself will show up in the list. | grep -v grep | will remove any greps from the pipe. what is the answer you settled on? This will explain [fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork%E2%80%93exec).

Comment: @GrantBowman, ah thx, the `grep -v grep` bit is a nice trick. Uh, a process was being started from /etc/init.d, looks like the start script and process are separate. Not sure how to determine if parent/child -- can't tell from `pstree`

Comment: As requested before, can you post the scripts and data you are getting now and what you think you want as a result?

Comment: I followed Alaa Ali's recommendation for the most part, that has worked for me